# Form input not getting through

Tags: database, forms, input, integer

I am new to php (at 60 years old I am converting from years of VBScript and ASP) and having difficulties with form handling. I have searched this and many other forums for a solution and cannot find one. I am trying to delete a record using input from a form;

My form code ($row[0] is the field ID, which auto increments and in this instance has a value of 3):-

```
 <form action="<?=$_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ?>" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[0]?>">
 <input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>
```

The handling page then runs without producing any errors, but the record is not deleted, so I tested the input value on the handling page and the reason appears to be because the value of the variable "id" is not getting through.

I tested the input value on the form page with:

```
echo $row[0]
```

and it definitely outputs the integer 3.

The problem manifests on the handling page, and my code for checking that I have received the form input is:

```
$id = (INT)$_post['id'];
echo 'Form input= ', $_post['id'], '<br>';
echo '$id= ', $id, '<br>';
```

which displays a blank space for the form input line
and 0 as the value for $id, when both should display the number 3

Can anyone tell me why the value for "id" is not getting sent to the handling page?

I expect the answer is simple but I cannot grasp it.

I hope I have explained the problem satisfactorily but if not, please let me know.

Comment: use $_POST instead of $_post ? Also try removing the (INT)...do a print_r($_POST) to see what values you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
echo 'Form input= ' . $_POST['id'] . '<br>';
echo 'id= ' . $id . '<br>';
```

$_POST is case sensitive in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Strings is concatenated with `.` not `,`

Also `'$id= '` would render the value of `$id` not $id

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I have been demented with it and it works now.

Comment: You are welcome. Please check the answer as your suggested answer with a green tick, next to the answer.